# Magento : Configurable product option selected

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, color-swatches

I have created a configurable product in Magento 1.9.3.0 with default Magento "
Configurable Swatches" feature. I have display all simple product with configurable product on product listing page.

I want that when I click on simple product(suppose : Red color product), open configurable product, selected with "Red color" option and Red color image display.

Please check http://uboardindia.com/shop/classic.html